# Unable to render useState, useEffect hooks in custom component package using microbundle & React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, microbundle

Hi I am trying to create a sample library using React 18.2.0 & Microbundle and Although library built successfully, but when it is consumed in the client app I'm getting the below error in console log:

[image: Error]

## Library source code

Below is my library code.

### `App.js`

```
import './App.css';
import Dropdown from "./components/Dropdown";

function App() {
   
  let dropdown_data = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];

    return (
      <div className="dropdown">
         <Dropdown jsonData={dropdown_data} />
      </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

### `src/components/Dropdown.js`

```
import React from "react";
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

export const Dropdown = (props) => {
    const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        loadData();
    }, []);
    const loadData = () => {
        setDropdown(props.jsonData);
    }
    return (
        <div className="dropdown">
            <select> {
                dropdown.map((item, index) => (
                    <option key={index}>
                        {item}</option>
                ))
            } </select>
        </div>
    )

}
```

### `src/lib.package.js`

```
export { Dropdown } from "./components/Dropdown.js";
```

### `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "libtestone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "./dist/lib.umd.js",
    "module": "./dist/lib.module.js",
    "source": "src/lib.package.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build:lib": "microbundle --jsx React.createElement --jsxFragment React.Fragment --jsxImportSource react"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "microbundle": "^0.15.0"
  }
}
```

## Client application source code

This is where I am consuming the package.

### `App.js`

```
import './App.css';
import {Dropdown} from "libtestone";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Dropdown />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I remember having a similar problem when using Webpack's Module Federation, it turned to be that there was multiple instances of React.

Comment: List `react` and `react-dom` as `peerDependencies`.

Comment: @Camilo How did u resolve it ?

Comment: @morganney where in the plugin ?

Comment: Dear @Madpop, Could you please specify how have you installed the `libtestone` package into the client application package? For example, have you installed it from an npm registry (`npm install libtestone`) or from a local file system (`npm install path/to/libtestone`)?

Comment: @SergeyVyacheslavovichBrunov No Via Local file system only npm i file:../libtestone and below is my repo  github.com/Devsnapper/reac-lib

Comment: @morganney  Tried this  in both app as well as in lib also it didnt work out

Comment: Please update the repo :)

Comment: @Madpop Please include your files in the repository proper, not in a .7z file.

Comment: @AymenHammami Content also matches

Comment: @AKX  U can extract the 7z file both the consumer and app library is there in zip file

Comment: @Madpop I know I could, but I really don't have the inclination to download a 7z archiver, download the file, extract it and look at the files, when they could just be in the repository.

Comment: @AKX https://github.com/Devsnapper/React-Package please check now

Comment: @Madpop You've added two submodules that point nowhere.

Comment: @Madpop did you try deleting node_modules and .lock file from client side and changing build:lib like in my edited answer?

Comment: @AymenHammami im working on that

Comment: @AKX Yes if u clone u will the get the folders and that's all  i can do  it for now

Comment: @Madpop Cloning the repository with `--recursive` gives me two empty folders.

Comment: @AKX can u check this url  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sUEmi2-vlADands7euYGYcGpwtDmOdjw?usp=sharing

Comment: @Madpop I don't remember exactly and I don't longer have access to the repo, but there was some setting in the Module Federation config that allowed you to list shared dependencies or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### libone

- Your library (`libone/`) **must not** have a hard dependency on `react`; a peer dependency is enough. (If you'd like it to have a self-contained demo app, then things are slightly different and I might recommend [Vite's library mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode) [like I've recently done here](https://github.com/akx/react-curved-input/blob/dce8c1fa891f8383254da1e07bbc5896b8da0662/vite.config.ts#L11-L27) instead of `microbundle`).
- The library should not depend on `react-scripts` in any way; it doesn't need to.

All in all, this `package.json` does the trick (the script being named `prepare` so the `dist/` files get built at a correct time; naturally you could still use `build:lib`, but then your `prepare` script must call it with e.g. `npm run build:lib`):

```
{
  "name": "libone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "source": "lib/index.js",
  "main": "./dist/lib.umd.js",
  "module": "./dist/lib.module.js",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "microbundle build --globals react=React,react-dom=ReactDOM --jsx React.createElement --jsxFragment React.Fragment --jsxImportSource react"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "microbundle": "^0.15.0"
  }
}
```

### userone

- The client application `userone` can use `react-scripts`, `vite`, or whatever way you like to build a React app.
- The client application's `dependencies` should contain React, ReactDOM, etc.

With a layout that has `libone/` and `userone/` as siblings, using react-scripts, `userone`'s package.json could be something like

```
{
  "name": "userone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "libone": "../libone",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test"
  }
}
```

In addition, if you use `npm link` or `yarn link` for `libone`, it's imperative that `libone`'s `node_modules/` directory does not contain React; that will confuse Webpack.

Comment: I tried the above approach and removed node_mod and package lock json and did a npm install after doing these changes still im getting the same invalid hook and can upload the repo which u worked.

Comment: Please see https://github.com/akx/so72942020 ...

Comment: Glad you got it to work. It might be a npm/yarn cache issue on the non-working machine, then.

Comment: a small thing how can i embedded the css ?

Comment: Different libraries do that in different ways. You might want to consider styled-components/emotion/... or just tell your users to `import 'libone/dist/foo.css';` in their app.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably put `react`, `react-dom` and `react-scripts` in `peerDependencies` so that they don't get bundled along with your library. That could be the reason you're facing this issue, since putting `react` in `dependencies` might create two instances of React.

**Edit:** The real culprit was the usage of `npm i file:../libone`.

Apparently this is an issue where it won't happen if you publish your library, because if `react` and `react-dom` are in `peerDependencies`, it will use the local instance of React.

However in your case, you have a library folder adjacent to a client app folder, and whenever you import your component from the library it's using its own instance of React from its `node_modules`, which is causing the errors.

In order to solve this, make sure to have the following:

- In libone: `package.json`:

  ```
  "devDependencies": {
    "microbundle": "^0.15.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "file:../userone/node_modules/react",
    "react-dom": "file:../userone/node_modules/react-dom",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
   }
  ```

Also change `build:lib` to this (not sure if it has a big impact but that's the setup I had):

```
  "build:lib": "microbundle build --globals react=React,react-dom=ReactDOM --jsx React.createElement --jsxFragment React.Fragment --jsxImportSource react"
```

- In userone: `package.json`:

  ```
  "dependencies": {
  "libone": "file:../libone",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
  "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  }
  ```

Make sure to remove both `node_modules`, run `npm install` in userone, then `npm install` in libone, then remove `dist` folder from libone and run `npm run build:lib`.

Notice that in libone `package.json` we're referencing the `react` and `react-dom` that are installed inside your userone folder, and that solves the problem of two React instances when using `npm i file:../libone`.

Comment: where should we add this in consumer app or plugin ?  here is my git repo https://github.com/Devsnapper/reac-lib

Comment: Tried this  in both app as well as in lib also it didnt work out.

Comment: You should add it to your plugin/lib. Make sure that you removed react, react-dom and react-scripts from dependencies and moved them to peerDependencies. Also make sure to delete node_modules and the .lock file when trying it with the client App

Comment: If that doesn't work, I added another possible solution in answer, hope it can help.

Comment: it didnt work and i changed the  build :lib command too

Comment: @Madpop I saw you pushed node_modules in github in the old repo, you don't want to do that. Did you delete the node_modules from client side and installed fresh after changing build:lib? Did you change the import to the newly created lib? Did any error change? Or are you getting same error?

Comment: its same error and by mistake node mod went and after changing build:lib also same and yes i changed to the new created lib and getting same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246432/discussion-between-madpop-and-aymen-hammami).

Comment: @Madpop I think I found the issue, it's related to using file:../ since if you publish the lib while it's using react as peerDependency it's going to use the React instance of that current project. This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021112/react-hooks-in-react-library-giving-invalid-hook-call-error

Comment: @ Aymen Hammami is it running for u ?

Comment: @Madpop yes just solved it, will update answer shortly

Comment: is it possible to update the folder in drive ?

Comment: @Madpop I just updated the answer. Make sure to follow the steps and if does not work let me know I might have forgotten a step or two, not that easy to remember all the changes I've tried. It's currently running for me. https://imgur.com/a/1wxguft

Answer (score 1):

## Introduction

Let's consider the following versions as the current versions:

- npm: `8.13.2`.

Let's consider the article that describes the same problem: [Invalid Hook Call Warning – React](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html).

## Changes to get reproducible example

### Client application (`apptestone`)

Since the provided (posted right in the question, not on GitHub) source code of the client application is not complete, I have created an example client application with Create React App:

```
/question-72942020/src$ npx create-react-app apptestone
```

### `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "apptestone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "13.5.0",
    "libtestone": "file:../libtestone",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

### Resulting directory structure

```
/question-72942020/src$ tree --charset unicode -L 2
.
|-- apptestone
|   |-- build
|   |-- node_modules
|   |-- package.json
|   |-- package-lock.json
|   |-- public
|   |-- README.md
|   `-- src
`-- libtestone
    |-- dist
    |-- node_modules
    |-- package.json
    |-- package-lock.json
    `-- src
```

## General changes

### Library package (`libtestone/package.json`): Reduce scope of dependencies

Update the file as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
},

<…>

"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
},

<…>

"devDependencies": {
  "microbundle": "^0.15.0",
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
  "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
  "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
  "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},
```

Run the command:

```
/question-72942020/src/libtestone$ npm clean-install
```

### Library component (`libtestone/src/components/Dropdown.js`): Use «fallback» value

Update the function as follows:

```
const loadData = () => {
    setDropdown(props.jsonData || ["Loaded data"]);
};
```

This will allow using the `Dropdown` component like it is shown in your example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Dropdown />
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Analysis

After making the changes described in the «Changes to get reproducible example» and «General changes» sections:

1. The problem has been reproduced.
2. The analysis has been started.

It is an important detail that you have installed the library package into the application package from a local file system (not from an npm registry).

It seems that had you installed the library from an npm registry, the changes described in the «General changes» section would be sufficient to solve the problem or would not be necessary at all.

It seems that the [«Duplicate React» problem](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react) takes place according to the symptom (the output):

```
/question-72942020/src/apptestone$ npm ls react
apptestone@0.1.0 /question-72942020/src/apptestone
├─┬ @testing-library/react@13.3.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ libtestone@0.1.0 -> ./../libtestone
│ ├─┬ @testing-library/react@13.3.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react@18.2.0 <!-- NOTE!
├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
└── react@18.2.0 <!-- NOTE!
```

Please, note the `<!-- NOTE!` markers.

The article states:

> This problem can also come up when you use `npm link` or an equivalent. In that case, your bundler might “see” two Reacts — one in application folder and one in your library folder.

## Possible solution

The article describes a possible solution:

> Assuming `myapp`and `mylib` are sibling folders, one possible fix is to run `npm link ../myapp/node_modules/react` from `mylib`. This should make the library use the application’s React copy.

Let's adapt the solution to the current case.

The resulting command:

```
/question-72942020/src/libtestone$ npm link ../apptestone/node_modules/react ../apptestone/node_modules/react-dom
```

Please, note the working directory path (before `$`).

Let's check the created symbolic links:

```
/question-72942020/src/libtestone$ ls -la node_modules/react{,-dom}
<…> node_modules/react -> ../../apptestone/node_modules/react
<…> node_modules/react-dom -> ../../apptestone/node_modules/react-dom
```

Let's check the duplication:

```
/question-72942020/src/apptestone$ npm ls react
apptestone@0.1.0 /question-72942020/src/apptestone
├─┬ @testing-library/react@13.3.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ libtestone@0.1.0 -> ./../libtestone
│ ├─┬ @testing-library/react@13.3.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped -> ./node_modules/react
│ ├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped -> ./node_modules/react
│ ├─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped -> ./node_modules/react
│ └── react@18.2.0 -> ./node_modules/react <!-- NOTE!
├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
└── react@18.2.0 <!-- NOTE!
```

Please, note the `<!-- NOTE!` markers.

This is it.

### Development workflow

Now it is possible to work on the library: make a change, build it (`npm run build:lib`).

Given that the application is started in the development mode (`npm start`), the library changes will be taken into account (upon library rebuild: `npm run build:lib`).

#### Caveat

It seems that every time a package installation npm command (`npm install`, etc.) is performed for the library project, the npm links will be reverted to module directories.
It is necessary to recreate them.

Comment: I think the issue really is just that the library has bundled react instead of using it as a dependency, which is a no-no.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are  multiple copies of React in the same bundle.

So there are some possible ways to solve this error:

1. Try to publish your package to NPM and then [import it directly from NPM](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991#issuecomment-435135293).
2. [A (hacky) workaround](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991#issuecomment-435343455) at the moment using npm-link-shared and a prestart npm script to essentially replace the one package's react dependency with a symlink to the other's, so they use the same instance.

   ```
     "prestart": "npm-link-shared ./node_modules/<other package>/node_modules . react"
   ```
3. It [can be resolved by adding](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991#issuecomment-435587809):

   ```
      alias: {
        react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react')
      }
   ```

to resolve property in webpack config of my main app.

**Alternative solution:**

As [React docs says](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react):

> In order for Hooks to work, the react import from your application
> code needs to resolve to **the same module as the react import from
> inside the react-dom package**.
>
> If these react imports resolve to two different exports objects, you
> will see this warning. This may happen if you accidentally end up with
> two copies of the react package.

So it looks like you need to check the above statement as you are developing separate library. How can is it possible to check? It is possible to check by:

**The First Way:**

If you use Node for package management, you can run this check in your project folder:

```
 npm ls react
```

If you see more than one React, you’ll need to figure out why this happens and fix your dependency tree. For example, maybe a library you’re using incorrectly specifies react as a dependency (rather than a peer dependency). Until that library is fixed, [Yarn](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) resolutions is one possible workaround.

**The second way:**

[You can also try to debug this problem](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react) by adding some logs and restarting your development server:

```
// Add this in node_modules/react-dom/index.js
window.React1 = require('react');

// Add this in your component file
require('react-dom');
window.React2 = require('react');
console.log(window.React1 === window.React2);
```

If it prints false then you might have two Reacts and need to figure out why that happened. This issue includes some common reasons encountered by the community.

Comment: i found some packages when i ran npm ls react and result i saw was deduplicated and im not sure how to remove those

Comment: @Madpop I am sorry, however, could you elaborate what you mean? Have you tried the first three solutions from my reply?

Comment: I followed the Alternative way 1. npm ls react and i found some deduped react versions and i cannot push the plugin to npm as i have to use internally only and the versions in both consumer and as well as in lib are same

Comment: @Madpop do you use `Webpack`?

Comment: using microbundle and tried roll up also  below is my rep github.com/Devsnapper/reac-lib

Comment: @Madpop  I suggest you to try the second and third ways and see whether it helped to you

Comment: @Madpop do you have `package.json` for your library where `dropdown` component is implemented

Comment: Yes in question it self i posted it under src/lib.package.js

Comment: @Madpop and what dependencies does it have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246430/discussion-between-madpop-and-stepup).